# Проверка ввода c++

Tags: c++, c, ввод

```
int a,b,n,m,i,j,max,arr[100][100],minarr[100];

do {
    cout << "Введите границу a\n";
    cin >> a;
    if (!(cin.good())){
        cout << "Неверно введена a\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.get();
}
} while (!(cin.good()));

do {
    cout << "Введите границу b\n";
    cin >> b;
    if (!(cin.good())) {
        cout << "Неверно введена b";
        cin.clear();
        cin.get();
    }

} while (!cin.good());

do {
    cout << "Введите кол-во строк n\n";
    cin >> n;
    if (!(cin.good()) || (n < 0) || (n > 100))
    {
        cout << "Неверно введено n" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.get();
    }

} while (!(cin.good()) || (n < 0) || (n > 100));

do {
    cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов m\n";
    cin >> m;
    if (!(cin.good()) || (m < 0) || (m > 100))
    {
        cout << "Неверно введено m" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.get();
    }

}while (!(cin.good()) || (n < 0) || (n > 100));
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin.get();` - этого мало. Вы вводите 1.6. Чтение затыкается на точке - и что дальше?...

Вот, возьмите готовый вариант с проверкой корректности ввода и диапазона:

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите размер массива",1,10);
```

Comment: Кажется сотню надо заменить на `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Этот код у меня написан для студентов, которые вечно начинали выяснять - что это за странная запись :), а тут просто скопировал, не глядя... Исправил.